# c++ passing parameter in a function gives error

Tags: c++, class

Im writing a class to convert Roman Numerals to Decimal. Roman Numeral comes from user input and then passed into the class function, but it keeps giving an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class romanType {



public:
    romanType();    //constructor

    void conversion(string numeral) {


        int len = strlen(numeral);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            cout << numeral[i];

    }
};


#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include"roman_class.h"
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    romanType number;   //declaring an instance of the class


    string numeral;
    cout << "Enter Roman Numeral to be converted";
    cin >> numeral;

    number.conversion(numeral);

    }
```

I keep getting these errors for "int len = strlen(numeral);":

```
Error (active) E0413 no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char *" exists Roman_Numeral

Error C2664 'size_t strlen(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *' Roman_Numeral
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` is a function meant to be used with C-style character arrays (e.g. `char x[10]`).

`std::string` is a class that has a `.size()` method. You can get the length of the string (and fix your code) by replacing:

```
int len = strlen(numeral);
```

with

```
int len = numeral.size();
```

Also, as per C++ rules, the size of the containers (string included) cannot be negative (obviously). The type used is `size_t`, not `int`. You can think about it as an unsigned integral type that can represent the size of the largest thing you can store. That was just to be pedantic, your code will work with `int` too.

Answer (score 0):

Either cast the string like the following:

```
int len = strlen((const char*)numeral.c_str());
```

or use the string method size():

```
int len = numeral.size();
```